# Display a number in text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have function where I want display a number in text.

```
if (all > 120)
{
     int w_m = 120 - il_os;
     string text = "free room: {0}", w_m;
     ModelState.AddModelError("", text);
}
```

but I have a error:

> Error 1   A local variable named 'w_m' is already defined in this scope

how display number with text in ModelState.AddModelError?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a function there:

```
string text = string.Format("free room: {0}", w_m);
```

Placeholders in strings isn't a language feature! Right now you're declaring the variable `w_m` again, as a `string`. That *is* a feature:

```
int a, b, c;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `String.Format` in order to format strings in that manner

```
string text = String.Format("free room: {0}", w_m);
```

Doing this will also remove the error you're seeing because the current syntax you're using is causing `w_m` to be redeclared as a `string` local.

Comment: He has declared the variable w_m once as an int (int w_m = 120 - il_ox;) and then again as a string.  He's declaring the variable 'text' as a string, then initializing it's value to "free room: {0}".  Then in the same line, declaring w_m as another string variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your error has nothing to do with displaying a number in text.  You are declaring a variable (`w_m`) that is already in that scope.

`w_m` must be declared prior to your `if` clause.  If you are looking to reuse your `w_m` variable, then change the above line to:

```
 w_m = 120 - il_os;
```

As for putting that number in your string, you can do a couple of things:

```
string text = "free room: " + w_m.ToString();
```

Or

```
string text = string.Format("free room: {0}", w_m);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 string text = string.Format("free room: {0}", w_m);
```

In your code the compiler thinks that w_m is another declaration, as in:

```
 string a, b;
```

Answer (score 0):

use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) which will be used like this:

```
string text = String.Format("free room: {0}", w_m);
```

Edit: Beaten to it, Should have known finding the MSDN link would cost me those precious seconds.